# Update data attribute on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found this project on the web: http://cyntss.github.io/Parallax-img-scroll/

And I am wondering if I want to change the `data-ps-vertical-position""` on resize how can I do that? I have tried updating the data value using the following approach: `$('div#frame-1').attr( 'data-ps-vertical-position','1900');` however it did not change the position of the element. If I reload the page with the right screen size it gets applied.

Please see below my approach of handling the responsive behaviour

```js
    (function($) {
     $(document).ready(function() {
      var width = $(document).width();
      $(window).resize(function() {
       //do something
       if (width < 900) {
        $('div#frame-1').css('bottom', 1900);
        $('div#frame-1').attr('data-ps-vertical-position', '1900');
       } else if (width > 901) {
        $('div#frame-1').css('bottom', 2500);
        $('div#frame-1').attr('data-ps-vertical-position', '2500');
       }
      }).resize();
     });
    })(jQuery);
```

Link to the [JS file](https://github.com/cyntss/Parallax-img-scroll/blob/master/demo/js/parallaxImg.js)

Comment: Setting the data attribute is not enough. You have to call the related event as well.

Comment: @Mojtaba I am really struggling. Have tried everythin I could can you help?

Comment: Do you have the whole code somewhere? So, I can find out the event listeners or functions must be called

Comment: https://github.com/cyntss/Parallax-img-scroll/blob/master/demo/js/parallaxImg.js yes this the code. Is this the parallaxImgScroll(); ?

Answer (score 0):

You declared `width` before `$(window).resize(function(){...})` so the width remains same when you resize it. Try moving `var width = $(document).width();` inside of `$(window).resize(function() {...})`

i.e.

```
(function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $(window).resize(function() {
                //do something
                var width = $(document).width();
                if (width < 900) {
                    $('div#frame-1').css('bottom', 1900);
                    $('div#frame-1').attr('data-ps-vertical-position', '1900');
                } else if (width > 901) {
                    $('div#frame-1').css('bottom', 2500);
                    $('div#frame-1').attr('data-ps-vertical-position', '2500');
                }
            }).resize();
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: The problem seems to arise again the moment I start scrolling

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you change the data values, you have to initiate the parallax again. SO, it's better to keep your desired settings in a global var.
For example, according to the link http://cyntss.github.io/Parallax-img-scroll/

If you need to apply your changes, it could be like this:

```
var parallaxSettings = {
        initialOpacity: 1, //from 0 to 1, e.g. 0.34 is a valid value. 0 = transparent, 1 = Opaque
        opacitySpeed: 0.1, //values from 0.01 to 1 -> 0.01: slowly appears on screen; 1: appears as soon as the user scrolls 1px
        pageLoader: true
    };

$(document).on("ready", function() {
    parallaxImgScroll(parallaxSettings);

});

(function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var width = $(document).width();
            $(window).resize(function() {
                //do something
                if (width < 900) {
                    $('div#frame-1').css('bottom', 1900);
                    $('div#frame-1').attr('data-ps-vertical-position', '1900');
                } else if (width > 901) {
                    $('div#frame-1').css('bottom', 2500);
                    $('div#frame-1').attr('data-ps-vertical-position', '2500');
                }
                parallaxImgScroll(parallaxSettings);
            }).resize();
        });
    })(jQuery);
```